# How to excecute fold expresion on types

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2017, variadic-templates

I try to ask if my type is convertable to any type of variadic template types using a fold Expression, but it does not work.

My try:

```
template<typename FromType, typename... ToType>
using enableIfPtrIsConvertible = std::enable_if_t<(false || std::is_convertible_v<FromType*, ToType*>...)>;
```

It does not compile:

> ```
> error C2059:  syntax error: '...'
> error C2976:  'std::enable_if_t': too few template arguments
> ```
>
> …

Can any one help me?

---

I tried as explained in the comments:

```
#include <type_traits>
template<typename FromType, typename... ToType>
using enableIfPtrIsConvertible = std::enable_if_t<(std::is_convertible_v<FromType*, ToType*> || ...)>;

class Base {};
class Derived :public Base {};

template <typename T, typename = enableIfPtrIsConvertible<T, Base, int>>
class Test {};

Test<Derived> tst1;
```

but I still get these compiler errors:

> ```
> 1>d:\vstest\odd\odd\isconvertible.h(3): error C2059: syntax error: '...'
> 1>d:\vstest\odd\odd\isconvertible.h(3): error C2976: 'std::enable_if_t': too few template arguments
> 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\xtr1common(59): note: see declaration of 'std::enable_if_t'
> 1>d:\vstest\odd\odd\isconvertible.h(11): error C2976: 'Test': too few template arguments
> 1>d:\vstest\odd\odd\isconvertible.h(9): note: see declaration of 'Test'
> 1>d:\vstest\odd\odd\isconvertible.h(11): error C2133: 'tst1': unknown size
> 1>d:\vstest\odd\odd\isconvertible.h(11): error C2641: cannot deduce template argument for 'Test'
> ```

---

This one works

```
template<typename FromType, typename... ToTypes>
constexpr bool is_ptr_convertible_v = (std::is_convertible_v<FromType*, ToTypes*> || ...);

template<typename FromType, typename... ToTypes>
using enableIfPtrIsConvertible = std::enable_if_t<is_ptr_convertible_v<FromType, ToTypes...>>;
```

But I don't understand why the direct combination dose not compile.

Answer (score 3):

```
template<typename FromType, typename... ToType>
using enableIfPtrIsConvertible = std::enable_if_t<false || (std::is_convertible_v<FromType*, ToType*> || ...)>;
```

you got the fold syntax wrong.  The problem has nothing to do with types.

Or:

```
template<typename FromType, typename... ToType>
using enableIfPtrIsConvertible = std::enable_if_t<(std::is_convertible_v<FromType*, ToType*> || ...)>;
```

which is the same, but cleaner.

Comment: The `false ||` part is entirely superfluous.

Comment: @T.C. True, but I was trying to keep it similar to the OP's.

Comment: @BabakPourat The code I wrote in the answer?  I did the least I could to make your code compile and do what you seem to want it to do.  I just had to move the `(` after the `false||`.  As T.C. noted, `false||` isn't needed, as an empty `||` fold expression evaluates to false

Comment: @ Yakk Unfortunately not. I've add the final test code and the errors to the question section (they are the same).

Comment: @babak try a new compiler or tell it to compile in C++17 mode.

Comment: @ Yack I check ist again C++17 is active (I can compile this: std::array values = { 1,2,3 };)